# Extract variable from special string format Python

Tags: python, string, extract

I have retrieve a string from an XML file which looks like this :

```
"[0, 30, -146, 0]$[-143, 30, -3, 0]" #[left, top, right, bottom]
```

(It is always the same format)

And i'm trying to extract both left values of both positions to have :

```
left1 = 0
left2 = -143
```

How can i do this please?

Comment: split by $, then do a `json.loads()` on the splitted item to get a list and access the list's first item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression:

```
import re
your_str = "[0, 30, -146, 0]$[-143, 30, -3, 0]" #[left, top, right, bottom]
reg = re.compile("\[(-?\d+),")
list_results = re.findall(reg, your_str)
# ['0', '-143']
# if you always have the same kind of str you can even do
# left1, left2 = map(int, re.findall(reg, your_str))  # map to change from str to int
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try without regex

```
string = "[0, 30, -146, 0]$[-143, 30, -3, 0]"
param = string.split("$") #split your string and get ['[0, 30, -146, 0]', '[-143, 30, -3, 0]']
letf = [] #list of your result

#note that param is a List but 'a' is a String
#if you want to acces to first element with index you need to convert 'a' to as list
for a in param:
    b = eval(a) #in this case'eval()' is used to convert str to list
    letf.append(b[0]) #get the first element of the List

print(letf)
```